# Is it possible to transfer files from a directory using SCP in Python but ignore hidden files or sym links?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, scp

I'm currently utilising Paramiko and SCPClient in Python to transfer a directory from one server to another as a means of backup. This works well however I do not want it to copy hidden files (.file_name) or symbolic links. Is this possible?

Unfortunately rsync isn't an option for me as it's not available on either of the remote servers I connect to. My script is below (sensitive info replaced with dummy data). Note I need to connect to a jump host before being able to connect to target_1 or target_2.

```
import os
import shutil
import time
import paramiko
from scp import SCPClient

#set up ssh variables
j_host = '00.00.00.00'
target_host_1 = '00.00.00.001'
target_host_2 = '00.00.00.002'
port_no = 22
username = ''
passw = ''

#set up temporary folder on local machine to store files
path = "/local_path/"
os.mkdir(path)

#create SSH Client for jump server
jump_host=paramiko.SSHClient()
jump_host.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
jump_host.connect(j_host, username=username, password=passw)

#set up channel to connect to 1 via jump server
jump_host_transport_1 = jump_host.get_transport()
src_addr = (j_host, port_no)
dest_addr_1 = (target_host_1, port_no)
jump_host_channel_1 = jump_host_transport_1.open_channel("direct-tcpip", dest_addr_1, src_addr)

#set up channel to connect to 2 via jump server
jump_host_transport_2 = jump_host.get_transport()
dest_addr_2 = (target_host_2, port_no)
jump_host_channel_2 = jump_host_transport_2.open_channel("direct-tcpip", dest_addr_2, src_addr)

#function which sets up target server, either 1 or 2
def create_SSHClient(server, port, user, password, sock):
    target=paramiko.SSHClient()
    target.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    target.connect(server, port, user, password, sock=sock)
    return target

#invoke above function to set up connections for 1 & 2
ssh_1 = create_SSHClient(target_host_1, port_no, username, passw, jump_host_channel_1)
ssh_2 = create_SSHClient(target_host_2, port_no, username, passw, jump_host_channel_2)

#delete old files in backup folder
command = "rm -rf /filepath/{*,.*}"
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_2.exec_command(command)
lines = stdout.readlines()
#print(lines)

#pause to ensure old directory is cleared
time.sleep(5)

#SCPCLient takes a paramiko transport as an argument, sets up file transfer connection
scp_1 = SCPClient(ssh_1.get_transport())
scp_2 = SCPClient(ssh_2.get_transport())

#get files from 1, store on local machine, put on 2
scp_1.get('/filepath/.', '/target_folder_local/', recursive=True)
scp_2.put('/target_folder_local/.', '/filepath/', recursive=True)

#remove temporary folder
shutil.rmtree(path)

#close connections
ssh_1.close()
ssh_2.close()
jump_host.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no API in `SCPClient` to skip hidden files or symbolic links.

---

For upload, it's easy, if you copy the [`SCPClient`'s code](https://github.com/jbardin/scp.py) and modify it as you need. See the `os.walk` loop in `_send_recursive` function.

If you do not want to modify the `SCPClient`'s code, you will have to iterate the files on your own, calling `SCPClient.put` for each. It will be somewhat less efficient, as it will start new SCP server for each file.

---

For download, you might be able to modify the `SCPClient` code to respond with non-zero code to `C` commands fed by the server for the files you do not want to download.

Check the `_recv_file` function. There where `name` is resolved, check for names or attributes of files you are not interested in downloading and do `chan.send('\x01')` and exit the function.

---

Though why do you want to use SCP? Use SFTP. It is much better suited for custom rules you need.

Paramiko does not have recursive SFTP transfer functionality (But pysftp does, see [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848)). But you won't be able to use it anyway, for the same reason you cannot use it with SCP. For your specific needs.

But check my answer to [Python pysftp get_r from Linux works fine on Linux but not on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50118919/850848). It shows a simple recursive SFTP download code. Just modify it slightly to skip the files you do not want to download.

Something like

```
if (not S_ISLNK(mode)) and (not entry.filename.startswith(".")):
```

(see [Checking if a file on SFTP server is a symbolic link, and deleting the symbolic link, using Python Paramiko/pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63033697/850848))

Comment: Thanks for your response, where would I find the related code for SCPClient?

Comment: I've added a link to my answer.

Comment: Hi @MartinPrikryl, sorry to bother you again. I've just come back to this project after having to put it on pause. Regarding your solution - this works for .put however I need to prevent .get from taking hidden files or sym links in the first place. According to the SCP code: **The get method is controlled by the remote scp instance, and behaves accordingly** . There doesn't seem to be scope to edit the .get function as it's resolved on the server side. I don't suppose you'd have any other suggestions on how I could go about achieving this without rsync?

Comment: Why are you using SCP in the first place? Why don't you use SFTP? It's better suited for this task.

Comment: Looking at Paramiko documentation there doesn't seem to be a recursive option for .get or .put when invoking .open_sftp() on a SSHClient.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you Martin, I'll take a look. If I could upvote twice I would! The last thing I would need to set up is pysftp.Connection through a jump host to the target server.

Comment: Well you can upvote some of the other answers I've linked, if they help you :)

Comment: For the jump host see [Port forwarding and the open SFTP using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63057035/850848). Though your code already does that. Doesn't it? I see you now ask for pysftp, while your code is for Paramiko. You do not need pysftp.

Comment: It does indeed, however If I'm to follow the pysftp solution you linked in the original edited comment - I would need to have my target server connect via pysftp.Connection() rather than SSHClient (Paramiko), but it first needs to go through the jump host.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what pysftp solution do you refer to.

Comment: After your second line break you link two threads which show solutions to implement, both of which rely on pysftp. Perhaps I've misunderstood your reply? The solutions seem to use pysftp specific parameters.

Comment: OK, I see, you mean this, right? [Python pysftp get_r from Linux works fine on Linux but not on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50118919/850848) – While it's indeed about pysftp, the code I have posted there actually (almost) works with Paramiko directly too. I've edited the answer there.